# How to model data for race results in PowerBi?

Tags: powerbi, sankey-diagram

I have data where a constant set of athletes compete in the same race every month. Each get a position 1st, 2nd... etc

I was wondering what visualization to choose to see the position results for rach race through time. I was thinking a sanke diagram such that each destination column would represent a single race results and the results would always be ordered from top down 1st 2nd... respectively. see below:

[image]

You can see that Bue got 2nd place in Race 1 and 2nd place in Race 2. Also, Purple 1st in Race 1 but had a bad lunch before the race and didn't do so well.

I haven't been able to adapt current resources to a sanke in this way.

Is this possible?
Is there another visualization that can accomplish the same idea?
How should the data be structured for this chart to work?

Thanks so much;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this with the [Sankey Chart visual](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380777):

[image: Sankey Chart]

However, you'll probably need to drag and drop the bars to get the order you want and manually set the colors how you want (not great if you need this fully automated).

This is how I set up the data:

[image: Data]

**Edit:**

A simple line chart will be easier to automate.

[image: Line Chart]

The data format is more intuitive too.

[image: Data]

Comment: Excellent solution! How did you colour the nodes in the sanke to gold, silver, bronze and grey?

Comment: All the formatting is done in the formatting tab of the visuals pane.

Comment: Indeed; However, I'm not seeing the option to colour the bars. I can colour the tracks in the "links" portlet. Still unsure as to colour the bars.

Comment: shoot, was using an older version of the snake. Nodes is present. Thanks for your help!